# @Autowired issue with @Configurable servlet

Tags: java, spring, autowired, configurable, eclipse-virgo

I am trying to autowire a class into a WebSocketServlet in the following way:

```
@Configurable(autowire=Autowire.BY_TYPE)
public class MyServlet extends WebSocketServlet {
    @Autowired
    public MyClass field;

    // etc...
}
```

Here's what my configuration looks like:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.*" />

<bean id="config" class="org.*.MyClass">
   <!-- a bunch of properties -->
</bean>
```

**Note that autowire used to work just fine as long as I was in a Spring `@Controller`**. I had to step out of that because i don't know how to map a WebSocketsServlet to a method of the `@Controller` as you do with regular servlets.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: @Configurable requires AspectJ load time or compile time weaving to work, it will not work with Spring AOP alone. Can you confirm that you have Aspectj With load/compile time weaving enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of @Configurable and doing the following in the servlet init method does the trick:

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
   super.init();
   SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use @Configurable, you need to have these line in tour context:

```
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="true"/>
<context:spring-configured/>    
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.*" />
```

In addition, I think you must reference spring-aspect in the Import-Library section of your Manifest.

I didn't succeed to make it work, there is a post on this in the Virgo forum at Eclipse.
If you succeed, let me know how  ;)

Comment: check my answer below - I had to drop @Configurable and use the SpringBeanAutowiringSupport stuff :)

Answer (score -4):

As per the [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)

Externalized values may be looked up by injecting the Spring Environment into  a `@Configuration` class using the `@Autowired` or the `@Inject` annotation:

```
 @Configuration
 public class AppConfig {
     @Inject Environment env;

     @Bean
     public MyBean myBean() {
         MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
         myBean.setName(env.getProperty("bean.name"));
         return myBean;
     }
 }
```